# np.allclose throws throws an TypeError: Not implemented for this type when dataframe has strings in a row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to compare the values within a data frame for equality within a given tolerance. np.allclose is the perfect candidate but when my data frames have string values it throws an TypeError: Not implemented for this type. I have no way of knowing if their will be string inside an row or not.

Example

```
old = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, np.nan, 3],
                    'b': [4,"OK", 6]},
                    index=['x', 'y', 'z'])

new = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, np.nan, 3],
                    'b': [4, "OK", 6]},
                    index=['x', 'y', 'z'])
```

Comment: You can check dtype on **columns** -- individually or with ```info()```.  Floats and ints can't have strings, objects can of course.

Comment: Is it the case that a single column can have both numeric and string values and you can't know in advance whether a specific row within that column has a string or numeric value, or is it that a row can contain either all string values or all numeric values? In the latter case it sounds like your rows should be columns and vice-versa. Please provide a sample DataFrame.

Comment: @JoeCondron its a case where a DataFrame can have both Numeric and String values

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I meant. It's not important whether a DataFrame has different types, it's important whether a single column has mixed types. DataFrames are work best when columns are of a single type. Normally, columns represent fields and rows represent records. For example, a DataFrame could contain the name and age of a group of people. In this case, it would usually be organised so that there is an age column (of type int or float) and a Name column of type object. Each row would then represent a person. Do you see my point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The columns 'b' in the example contains mixed types; strings and ints. 
You can't compare strings with allclose as strings are either different or not. 
You should, if possible, have your data organised so that columns are of a single type. If you had, you could use np.allclose to compare the numeric columns and the standard `==` operator to compare the columns containing strings. 
In the example, columns 'a' are numeric so np.allclose works:

```
In [25]: np.allclose(old.a, new.a)
Out[25]: False
```

However, it returned `False` because equating null values always returns `False`, which is another subtlety you need to be be aware of when comparing DataFrames. In this case you could do

```
In [25]: np.allclose(old.fillna(value=0).a, new.fillna(value=0).a)
Out[25]: True
```

In the small example you give, the transpose of the DataFrame has columns of a single type so maybe you should be working with that. Note, however, that simply taking the transpose won't change the data types.

```
In [18]: old.T.dtypes

Out[18]:
x    object
y    object
z    object
```

but using the convert_objects method will

```
In [20]: old.T.convert_objects().dtypes
Out[20]:
x    float64
y     object
z    float64
dtype: object
```

In general, you can check the dtypes of each columns by calling DataFrame.dtypes. You can pick out string (object) columns with something like

```
obj_cols = df.columns[df.dtypes == object]
num_cols = df.columns[df.dtypes != object]   #this would also include any time columns
```

Then do

```
np.allclose(df1[num_cols].fillna(0), df2[num_cols].fillna(0))
```

and

```
(df1[obj_cols].fillna('') == df2[obj_cols].fillna('')).all().all()
```

EDIT:
In a more general setting you might want to be a bit more careful when handling nans. You could do the above, but also make sure that the null entries match exactly, since replacing nans with 0 might give an unwanted equality (you might have a 0 in one DataFrame and nan in another and you would still get equality, likewise for strings). You can do this as follow:

```
(old.isnull() == new.isnull()).all().all()
```

Comment: You're welcome. See the edit for a more robust handling of null values.